# Angular Material slider direction issues

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, right-to-left

I have an [angular material slider](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider) that needs to reside inside a `div` with a `dir="rtl"` style. However, when ever I add the `dir="rtl"` tag the slider is getting all messed up (the mouse isn't capturing it correctly and coloring is not accurate).
Here's a full HTML example of the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.3/angular-material.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl" dir="rtl">
        <md-slider min="0" max="255" ng-model="value" aria-label="red" id="red-slider">
        </md-slider>
        Value: {{value}}
    </div>
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.3/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
        .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I've tried changing the direction of the slider itself and placing it inside another `div dir="ltr"` but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.3/angular-material.css">
    <style>
    [dir=ltr] md-slider .md-thumb {
      left: auto;
      right: auto;
    }
    [dir=ltr] md-slider .md-thumb-container {
        left: 0;
        right: auto; 
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl" dir="rtl">

    <div dir="ltr">
    test
        <md-slider min="0" max="255" ng-model="value" aria-label="red" id="red-slider">
        </md-slider>
     </div>

        Value: {{value}}
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.3/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
        .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

when you override this class it seems to work